# AVFoundation video capture won't save

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to capture video. All seems to be well in my app until I get to here:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
  fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
            error:(NSError *)error
{

NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");

BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
if ([error code] != noErr)
{
    // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
    id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
    if (value)
    {
        RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
    }
}
if (RecordedSuccessfully)
{
    //----- RECORDED SUCESSFULLY -----
    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    if ([library videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL])
    {
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {

             }
         }];
    }

    [library release];      

}
```

}

When running it on a device I receive the "didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success" message, and then it crashes and I get this error:

Video /private/var/mobile/Applications/EDC62CED-3710-45B2-A658-A2FE9238F517/tmp/output.mov cannot be saved to the saved photos album: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12950 "Movie could not be played." UserInfo=0xe6749b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Movie could not be played.}

I haven't been able to find a whole lot of information about this anywhere and am not really sure what's going on.

Here's the code with the temporary output URL:

```
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"];
NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
{
    NSError *error;
    if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:&error] == NO)
    {
        //Error - handle if requried
    }
}
[outputPath release];
//Start recording
[movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:outputURL recordingDelegate:self];

[outputURL release];
```

I've already tried releasing the outputURL elsewhere after it saves, and that didn't help, so I don't think that's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I was an idiot and kept overlooking the fact that I didn't actually connect the video input to the capture session. Whoops.